Airflow Dags are not executed
I know almost nothing about Airflow. We have an application which internally uses Airflow for some tasks. After a black out and abrupt power off Airflow seems to be stuck.
In the log I can see something called 'scheduler' (don't know if it is a common component of Airflow or something customized for us) is doing its job and detects some new activities on Dags. Our 'core' dag '_trigger_update' is reported with the following stats:

queued:
success: 14678
running: 6
failed:

but clicking on it to see its internal details it seems to be only scheduled or queued.
It is automatically scheduled and pushing play button for a manual execution nothing changes. How can I force its execution ? How can I check and reset Airflow queue ?
Update 1
The entire application runs inside docker, I'm reading about airflow-worker. According to docker ps -a it is not running, maybe dags are not running because this component crashed. After a manual restart airflow-worker exits after few seconds. If this is the root cause what can I do to restore airflow-worker health ?
